# ImageView with OnClickListener not functioning

Tags: android, eclipse, imageview, onclicklistener

I'm new to android development and have tried to set up an ImageView with an OnClickListener. I want a new activity to open once the ImageView is clicked. I have created a new menu in XML which I want to be opened and have referenced it in Java and supposedly set everything up correctly according to many of the tutorials I follow. Here's my code, hopefully someone can help.

```
package com.youtube.iamjackpot;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class searchmenu extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.searchmenu);

    ImageView SearchButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.SearchButton);
    SearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent opensearchmenu = new Intent(
                    "com.youtube.iamjackpot.searchmenu");
            startActivity(opensearchmenu);
        }

    });

}
}
```

> Here's the XML of the page of I want to open:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/searchmenu" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background_meduim"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> And here's my main XML that contains the "Search Button" ImageView

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/TopTwoButtons"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background_meduim"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ListButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:src="@drawable/list_button_medium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/SearchButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ListButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/search_button_medium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/PopularButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/SearchButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/SearchButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
        android:src="@drawable/popular_button_medium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/InfoButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ListButton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/PopularButton"
        android:src="@drawable/info_button_meduim"
         />

</RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

@blackbelt Yeah, sorry about not adding the actual problem. When I click the "Search" button, nothing happens as if it wasn't set up at all.

Comment: post your manifest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
Intent opensearchmenu = new Intent(searchmenu.this,
                "Actvity name");
        startActivity(opensearchmenu);
```

For example

```
 Intent opensearchmenu = new Intent(searchmenu.this,
                FirstActivity.class);
        startActivity(opensearchmenu);
```

Note : Activiy name will be your class name you want to open on imageview click.

Comment: When I use either of the code you send me, I get an error saying "no enclosing instance of the type is accessible in scope" with "searhemenu.this" highlighted?

Comment: @Jaack - try this Intent opensearchmenu = new Intent(this,
                FirstActivity.class);

Comment: When I try that I get an error saying "the constructor intent is undefined"?

Comment: @Jaack  use this it will work without any error Intent opensearchmenu = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), FirstActivity.class);

Comment: Thank you so much, It works. I have been trying to resolve this issue for literally 5 hours. Thank you and everybody else for your help, much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're creating your Intent the wrong way, you need to use the .class reference of the Activity you want to open instead:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(searchmenu.this, youractivityclassname.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this change in your code--
    `Intent opensearchmenu = new Intent(SearchMenu.this,newActivity.class);
            startActivity(opensearchmenu);`

Comment: When I use the code you send me, I get an error saying "no enclosing instance of the type is accessible in scope" with "searchmenu.this" highlighted?

Answer (score 0):

first you add your other activity to the manifest and then you can use .

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SearchMenu.this, MyOtherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

for an example :

```
<activity android:name="MyOtherActivity" />
```

Comment: I already added "<activity android:name="searchmenu" /> to my manifest